# Javascript - Scans Text Corresponding to a Certain Label

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the text below:

```
This is a code update

* Official Name:  Noner


* Pub: https://content.upcodes.co/viewer/washington/wa-mechanical-code-2021

* Agency:  Agency Ni

* Reference: 

https://web.archive.org/web/20230226234118/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/agency/BuildingCodeCouncil.htm

https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#1)

* Citation: WAC 51-52 / WSR 23-02-055

* Draft Doc Title: 

 WSR 23-02-055 (#1)

* Draft Source Doc: https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#1)

* Draft Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pYmwQS3t-ZX-Vyg9yBabtIpXZ7By2G6f/view?usp=share_link ( #1)

* Final Doc Title: 

   IECC Com Update(#1)

   IECC Res Update (#2)

   IECC Res Update (#3)

* Final Source Doc: 
  https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022130/https://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&full=true&pdf=true (#1)
 https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#2)

* Final Drive: https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022130/https://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&full=true&pdf=true (#1)

https://web.archive.org/web/2023030302fdfdfg2130/https://apps.legfdg.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&fdsfullfdsf=true&pfdsfdf=true  (#2)

* Effective Date: January 4, 2023
```

I want to extract the information corresponding to the tag 'Reference:' but the code below only gives me one line. I want to scan all text until it encounters the asterisk symbol.

```
//Extract Reference    
var reference = description.search("Reference:");
if(reference != -1){
  reference = description.match(/(?<=^\* Reference\s*:)[\s]*[\n]*[^\n\r]*/m);  
  reference  = reference?.[0].trim();   
}else{
  reference = '';
}
console.log('Reference: ' + reference);
```

Expected Output:

```
https://web.archive.org/web/20230226234118/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/agency/BuildingCodeCouncil.htm

https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I decided to follow @Nick's idea not making any assumption about the 'subject' string.

I produced two lenient approaches in the sense that they work:

- when there's no *Reference* item (returning an empty string),
- when the *Reference* item has an empty content,
- and when the *Reference* item content is at the end of the string (thus not followed by an other item).

The first works in all cases whatever the content:

```
let ref_pat = /^\* Reference:\s*(.*\S(?:\s+.*\S)*?)??\s*(?:^\*|(?![\s\S]))/m;
let reference = description.match(ref_pat)?.[1] ?? '';
```

A second more efficient pattern is possible if you assume the content doesn't contain asterisk characters:

```
let ref_pat = /^\* Reference:\s*([^*]*[^*\s])/m;
let reference = description.match(ref_pat)?.[1] ?? '';
```

This is the only break, but this one is from far more simple.

Whatever the one you choose, the result is already trimmed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regex:

```
(?:^|\n)\*\s*Reference:\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\s*\n\*|$)
```

Which matches:

- `(?:^|\n)\*\s*Reference:\s*` : `* Reference:`  at the beginning of a line
- `([\s\S]*?)` : a minimal number of characters, captured in group 1
- `(?=\s*\n\*|$)` : a positive lookahead for spaces, a newline and a `*` or end-of-line

Regex demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vxTMBJ/3)

```js
text = `* Agency:  Agency Ni

* Reference: 

https://web.archive.org/web/20230226234118/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/agency/BuildingCodeCouncil.htm

https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#1)

* Citation: WAC 51-52 / WSR 23-02-055
`

reference = text.match(/(?:^|\n)\*\s*Reference:\s*([\s\S]*?)(?=\s*\n\*|$)/)?.[1] ?? ''

console.log(reference)
```

Comment: If you assume there's no asterisk in the content (there's only links after all), you can improve the pattern like that: `/^\* Reference:\s*([^*]*[^*\s])/m` (as in your pattern, no need to trim after, but this time the final lookahead becomes useless).

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte that's a good point. My regex is almost certainly over-engineered for the likely data, I've just tried to take account of all possibilities. I think you should post that one as a separate answer.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I see you did...

Comment: Yes, finally :)

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript with lookarounds:

```
(?<=^\* Reference\s*:\s*)\S[^]*?(?=^\s*\*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert that from the current position to the left is:

  - `^\* Reference\s*:\s*` Match `* Reference` followed by `:` between optional whitespace chars at the start of the string
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `\S` Match a non whitespace char
- `[^]*?` Match any character including newlines, as few as possible
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert that to the right is:

  - `^\s*\*` Match optional whitespace chars followed by `*` at the start of the string
- `)` Close te lookahead

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tiiNaV/1).

```js
const regex = /(?<=^\* Reference\s*:\s*)\S[^]*?(?=^\s*\*)/gm;
const s = `This is a code update

* Official Name:  Noner


* Pub: https://content.upcodes.co/viewer/washington/wa-mechanical-code-2021

* Agency:  Agency Ni

* Reference: 

https://web.archive.org/web/20230226234118/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/agency/BuildingCodeCouncil.htm

https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#1)

* Citation: WAC 51-52 / WSR 23-02-055

* Draft Doc Title: 

 WSR 23-02-055 (#1)

* Draft Source Doc: https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#1)

* Draft Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pYmwQS3t-ZX-Vyg9yBabtIpXZ7By2G6f/view?usp=share_link ( #1)

* Final Doc Title: 

   IECC Com Update(#1)

   IECC Res Update (#2)

   IECC Res Update (#3)

* Final Source Doc: 
  https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022130/https://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&full=true&pdf=true (#1)
 https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#2)

* Final Drive: https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022130/https://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&full=true&pdf=true (#1)

https://web.archive.org/web/2023030302fdfdfg2130/https://apps.legfdg.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&fdsfullfdsf=true&pfdsfdf=true  (#2)

* Effective Date: January 4, 2023
`;

const m = s.match(regex);
if (m) console.log(m[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use lookarounds:

```
(?<=Reference: )(.|\n)*?(?=\*)
```

Then trim the output.

Code example or [playground](https://regex101.com/r/qbSddu/1):

```js
const text = `This is a code update

* Official Name:  Noner


* Pub: https://content.upcodes.co/viewer/washington/wa-mechanical-code-2021

* Agency:  Agency Ni

* Reference: 

https://web.archive.org/web/20230226234118/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/agency/BuildingCodeCouncil.htm

https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#1)

* Citation: WAC 51-52 / WSR 23-02-055

* Draft Doc Title: 

 WSR 23-02-055 (#1)

* Draft Source Doc: https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#1)

* Draft Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pYmwQS3t-ZX-Vyg9yBabtIpXZ7By2G6f/view?usp=share_link ( #1)

* Final Doc Title: 

   IECC Com Update(#1)

   IECC Res Update (#2)

   IECC Res Update (#3)

* Final Source Doc: 
  https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022130/https://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&full=true&pdf=true (#1)
 https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#2)

* Final Drive: https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022130/https://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&full=true&pdf=true (#1)

https://web.archive.org/web/2023030302fdfdfg2130/https://apps.legfdg.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&fdsfullfdsf=true&pfdsfdf=true  (#2)

* Effective Date: January 4, 2023`

const patt = /(?<=Reference: )(.|\n)*?(?=\*)/gm
console.log(text.match(patt)?.[0].trim())
```

Answer (score 1):

**Avoid regex**, it reduces readability and performance.

In your case, the input can be very long, but the target pattern is quite simple.

The idea is to find '* Reference' and extract all the string until next '*'.

So we get to use `string.indexOf` and `string.substring`.

```js
const text = `
* Official Name:  Noner


* Pub: https://content.upcodes.co/viewer/washington/wa-mechanical-code-2021

* Agency:  Agency Ni

* Reference: 

https://web.archive.org/web/20230226234118/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/agency/BuildingCodeCouncil.htm

https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#1)

* Citation: WAC 51-52 / WSR 23-02-055

* Draft Doc Title: 

 WSR 23-02-055 (#1)

* Draft Source Doc: https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#1)

* Draft Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pYmwQS3t-ZX-Vyg9yBabtIpXZ7By2G6f/view?usp=share_link ( #1)

* Final Doc Title: 

   IECC Com Update(#1)

   IECC Res Update (#2)

   IECC Res Update (#3)

* Final Source Doc: 
  https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022130/https://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&full=true&pdf=true (#1)
 https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022030/https://lawfilesext.leg.wa.gov/law/wsr/2023/02/23-02-055.htm (#2)

* Final Drive: https://web.archive.org/web/20230303022130/https://apps.leg.wa.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&full=true&pdf=true (#1)

https://web.archive.org/web/2023030302fdfdfg2130/https://apps.legfdg.gov/wac/default.aspx?cite=51-52&fdsfullfdsf=true&pfdsfdf=true  (#2)

* Effective Date: January 4, 2023
`;
 
const pre = text.indexOf('* Reference');
const start = text.indexOf('h', pre);
const end = text.indexOf('*', start);
const slice = text.substring(start, end);
console.log({ slice });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
const match = description.match(/(?<=\* Reference\s*:)[\s\S]*?\*/)[0].slice(0, -1);
console.log(match)
```

This RegEx uses the look behind you used in your question, but then matches any character (including newlines) until the next `*` character. I used `.slice()` to get rid of the last character because the RegEx will match that last `*` character too.

I benchmarked this code against the other answers and found that it was the fastest by about 50% ([see benchmark here](https://jsbench.me/udlf4pcck5/1)).