# Debug a Regular Expression in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have this text stored in a variable called description:

```
`This is a code update`



*Official Name:

*Pub:

*Agency:

*Reference: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FFTgytIIcMYnCCgp2cKuUWIwdz7MFolLzCci_-OQn9c/edit#heading=h.81ay6ysgrxtb
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FFTgytIIcMYnCCgp2cKuUWIwdz7MFolLzCci_-OQn9c/edit#heading=h.81ay6ysgrxtb

*Citation: rg



*Draft Doc Title:

*Draft Source Doc:

*Draft Drive:



*Final Doc Title:

*Final Source Doc:

*Final Drive:
    
*Effective Date:
```

Using my code below, it returns an array with two elements:

```
//3. Extract Reference    
var reference = description.search("Reference");
if(reference != -1){        
    reference = description.match(/(?<=^\*\s*Reference\s*:)[\s]*[\n]*.*?(?=\n\*)/ms);   
    reference  = reference?.[0].trim();  
    reference = reference.split(/[\r\n]+/);        
}else{
    reference = '';
}
console.log('Reference:');
console.log(reference);
```

Output:

["https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FFTgytIIcMYnCCgp2cKuUWIwdz7MFolLzCci_-OQn9c/edit#heading=h.81ay6ysgrxtb","https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FFTgytIIcMYnCCgp2cKuUWIwdz7MFolLzCci_-OQn9c/edit#heading=h.81ay6ysgrxtb"]

However, when I change my description text to :

```
`This is a code update`   


*Official Name:

*Pub:

*Agency:

*Reference: 

*Citation: rg



*Draft Doc Title:

*Draft Source Doc:

*Draft Drive:



*Final Doc Title:

*Final Source Doc:

*Final Drive:



*Effective Date:
```

The code returns `*Citation: rg`. It should return an empty string. Where did I go wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: You can use for instance sites like https://regex101.com which will explain and highlight various parts of your regex/matches ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problems

Here's a trick used by many programmers as their first step in debugging: they explain their code to a rubber duck.

```
/                           
  (?<=^\*\s*Reference\s*:)  # Match after '* Reference:'
  [\s]*[\n]*                # 0 or more whitespaces followed by 0 or more line breaks
  .*?                       # 0 or more characters, including line breaks, lazily
  (?=\n\*)                  # until we meet a line break followed by '*'
/ms                         # with '^' stands for start of line and '.' for all characters.
```

Which [matches](https://regex101.com/r/V2ry46/1):

```
/
  '*Reference:'
  '\n'
  '*Citation: rg\n\n'
  '\n\*'               # Followed by 'Draft Doc Title'
/
```

Also, `[\s]*[\n]*` is effectively the same as `\s*`, as '\n' is a subset of '\s'.

### Solution

```
/
  (?<=^\*\s*Reference\s*:)  # Match after '* Reference:'
  (?:                       # a non-capturing group, consists of
    .                       # a character
    (?!^\*)                 # which is not followed by a '*' at the start of a line
  )*                        # 0 or more times
/ms
```

Try it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/8lj6X6/1)

Comment: too bad there's no `re.VERBOSE` in javascript

Comment: I'll surely wait for that future...

Comment: I guess we can use a string template like `VerboseRegex`.... whatever and generate a Re from it with a couple of simple replacements

Comment: That does sound like a good idea. Time to whip up a library :P

Answer (score 0):

You could update the pattern from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75712326/5424988) and match at least a single non whitespace char after `*Reference:`  on the same line.

Using JavaScript:

```
(?<=^\*\s*Reference[^\S\n]*:[^\S\n]*)\S[^]*?(?=^\s*\*)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert that to the left is

  - `^\*\s*Reference` Match `*Reference` at the start of the string
  - `[^\S\n]*:[^\S\n]*` Match `:` between optional spaces without newlines
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `\S` Match a non whitespace character
- `[^]*?` Match any character including newlines, as few as possible
- `(?=^\s*\*)` Positive lookahead, assert the start of the string, match optional whitespace chars and then `*`

See a [match here](https://regex101.com/r/kzhBX2/1) and [no match here](https://regex101.com/r/NK7kkD/1).

If you want to return an empty string instead of no match, you can omit matching a non whitespace character:

```
(?<=^\*\s*Reference[^\S\n]*:)[^]*?(?=^\s*\*)
```

See a [match here](https://regex101.com/r/ojaV1u/1) and [matching a space here](https://regex101.com/r/JJKu2f/1).